# Dynamic query returns multiple data

Tags: database

I have a quite simple query :
(find all nodes, fetch 3 fields from the node table and join the results with some tax.terms)

```
$query = db_select ( 'node', 'n' );
  $query->fields ( 'n', array( 
      'nid',
      'title',
      'type' ));
  $query->fields('b',array('body_value'));
  $query->fields('ttd',array('name'));

  $query->leftJoin ( 'field_data_body', 'b', 'b.entity_id = n.nid');
  $query->leftjoin ( 'taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'ti.nid = n.nid');
  $query->leftjoin ( 'taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd', 'ttd.tid = ti.tid AND ttd.vid = "5"');

  /* $query->condition('ttd',5); */

  $result = $query->execute ()->fetchAll ();
```

Now the problem is that i want a single object returned form the query for each node.
Like this :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [nid] => 557
    [title] => Lorem ipsum
    [type] => content_type
    [body_value] => lorem ispum
    [name] => taxonomy_term_value
)
```

But what i get is multiple objects because of the taxonomy index table (where a node can have anywhere **from 12 term id's to none at all**) but i only need 1 that corresponds to the condition stated above in the query (vid = 5, from the tax.term data table) **if** that node has a link to the tax.term, if the node does not have link it should return nothing,null,empty string...

So my results are as follows :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [nid] => 155
    [title] => lorem ipsum
    [type] => content_type
    [body_value] => lorem ispum
    [name] => 
)
stdClass Object
(
    [nid] => 3411
    [title] => lorem ipsum
    [type] => content_type
    [body_value] => lorem ispum
    [name] => value1
)
stdClass Object
(
    [nid] => 161
    [title] => lorem ipsum
    [type] => content_type
    [body_value] => lorem ispum
    [name] => value4
)
stdClass Object
(
    [nid] => 561
    [title] => lorem ipsum
    [type] => content_type
    [body_value] => lorem ispum
    [name] => value16
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you get currently is what you asked for: `leftJoin`.

To get only the single object you're looking for, you must use `join` instead (which is default and equivalent to `innerJoin`).

BTW you may simplify your code using the short notation, like this:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'type' ))
  ->fields('b', array('body_value'))
  ->fields('ttd',array('name'))
  ->join('field_data_body', 'b', 'b.entity_id = n.nid')
  ->join('taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'ti.nid = n.nid')
  ->join('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd', 'ttd.tid = ti.tid AND ttd.vid = "5"');
```

Comment: But won't this return only results that have a value in ttd.name ? Because each node has a taxonomy term which is not required so it can be null.

Comment: Not sure to correctly understand your last comment. Anyway what is certain is: the innerJoin will not return a record where there is no link between a node and the searched ttd, but will always return it otherwise, whatever the ttd.name value is (in other words when it is present, even if empty).

Comment: My question was exactly what you described what will happen, which is not a solution sadly to my problem, since there has to be a result even if the node does not have link to the matched ttd.name.

In short, there has to be a result for every node even if a node does not have a link between it and the tax.term (vid = 5) ,it should return an empty string.

    [name] =>

Comment: Now I don't understand at all. Reading your original question I believed that, with leftJoin: 1. you got too much resulting records (i.e. including those ones without a link to the (as condition says) ttid; 2. you wanted to get only those WITH a link ("i only need 1 that corresponds to the condition stated"). Can you edit your question adding a example with some detailed real records involved?

Comment: I'm sorry , i can have trouble sometimes explaining my thoughts correctly.
I've edited the original answer.